# Scaling the data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, scaling

I want to scale my "y" data with some function in Gnuplot.

My data file   "LB.dat"

```
 #x            #y
0.393000E+01 0.777894E+01
0.394000E+01 0.878703E+01
0.395000E+01 0.995059E+01
0.396000E+01 0.113780E+02
0.397000E+01 0.132372E+02
0.398000E+01 0.158209E+02
0.399000E+01 0.197064E+02
0.400000E+01 0.261749E+02
0.401000E+01 0.378215E+02
0.402000E+01 0.413921E+02
0.403000E+01 0.187385E+01
0.404000E+01 0.479743E+01
0.405000E+01 0.209362E+02
0.406000E+01 0.615307E+02
0.407000E+01 0.192419E+03
0.408000E+01 0.822545E+02
0.409000E+01 0.147813E+02
0.410000E+01 0.253664E+01
0.411000E+01 0.964172E-01
0.412000E+01 0.443564E+00
```

I want to scale my "y" data using the function exp(-a*"y") where 'a' is some constant.

## Here is my script file.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced "Helvetica" 18 color
set output "scaling.eps"
set size 1,1
set xlabel "x" font "Helvetica,22"
set xrange[0:100]
set logscale y
set format y "10^{%L}"
set ylabel "y" font "Helvetica,22"

plot "LB.dat" using 1:exp(-0.5*$2) w l lw 1.5 lc 'blue' title "scaledLB"
```

When I run it I am getting an error message " plot "LB.dat" using 1:exp(-0.5*$2) w l lw 1.5 lc 'blue' title "scaledLB"

```
                               ^
     "scale.gp", line 13: undefined value "
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a formula with columns put the whole expression into `()`,
i.e. `(exp(-0.5*$2))`

```
plot "LB.dat" using 1:(exp(-0.5*$2)) w l lw 1.5 lc 'blue' title "scaledLB"
```